# Can users get my database infos from my source

Tags: php, mysql

I had to make some .php lines for a project for me and a friend. I will post the sources below. I was wondering if the users visiting my pages would be able to fetch my database infos from my source. If yes. is there any ways to prevent this.

my admin.php
http://pastebin.com/K4hhrJK1

my index.php
http://pastebin.com/kmiQBF94

Sorry for the pastebin links. I've tried for the last 15 mins to get my .php code to show in a code box wich didnt work, it was actualy showing parts of the html on the thread.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to not have any connection info in your front end code. Create classes and let the classes do the database work. Create a database.php with all of your connection information and include that in the files with the classes.

Comment: Could you give more example of your concept. I understand the part of creating a db.php but how can I actualy make my index and admin .php fetch the data from db.php ? Thanks alot. This would actualy be good security for my db

Comment: In your db.php you would do your connection work, and create functions that return data... In the front (admin.php or index.php) you include the db.php file and create an instance of the class that the functions are in ($db = new myDatabaseClass, $array = $db->myFunction) - if you want to send me a message, I will give you some example files to start with.

Answer (score 1):

If your web server is properly configured, then visitors cannot see the PHP source code, and therefore cannot get your DB credentials.  But there are many ways to mis-configure a server to make it possible.